# Solution of $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{(\sigma+1)x}{\sigma x+1}$ in terms of Lambert $w$ function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Solution of $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{(\sigma+1)x}{\sigma x+1}$ in terms of Lambert $w$ function.

Should I first take the solution of ODE and then apply Laplace transform. Please give step by step solution if possible

Comment: This is a separable equation. Do you see how to separate and integrate the DE? You will end up with an implicit solution.

Answer (score 1):

lets take $\sigma x = \phi$
then
$$
\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -\dfrac{(\sigma+1)x}{\sigma x + 1}
$$
transforms to
$$
\dfrac{d\phi}{dt} = -(\sigma+1)\dfrac{\phi}{\phi+1}
$$
re-arrange leads to
$$
\int 1+\dfrac{1}{\phi}d\phi = \phi + \ln \phi = \int -(\sigma+1) dt = -(\sigma+1)t + C
$$
thus
$$
\phi\mathrm{e}^{\phi} = C_1\mathrm{e}^{-(\sigma+1)t}
$$
when t = 0 we find
$$
C_1 = \phi(t=0)\mathrm{e}^{\phi(t=0)} = \sigma x(t=0) \mathrm{e}^{\sigma x(t=0)} 
$$
thus
$$
\phi\mathrm{e}^{\phi} = \sigma x(t=0) \mathrm{e}^{\sigma x(t=0)} \mathrm{e}^{-(\sigma+1)t}
$$
thus

$$
\phi\mathrm{e}^{\phi} = \sigma x(t=0) \mathrm{e}^{\left(\sigma x(t=0) -(\sigma+1)t\right)}
$$
now using a standard result 
$$
Y = X\mathrm{e}^X \implies X = W(Y)
$$
thus
$$
\phi\mathrm{e}^{\phi} = \sigma x(t=0) \mathrm{e}^{\left(\sigma x(t=0) -(\sigma+1)t\right)}
$$
leads to
$$
\phi = W\left[\sigma x(t=0) \mathrm{e}^{\left(\sigma x(t=0) -(\sigma+1)t\right)}\right]
$$
now transforming back to $x$
we find

$$
x(t) = \dfrac{W\left[\sigma x(t=0) \mathrm{e}^{\left(\sigma x(t=0) -(\sigma+1)t\right)}\right]}{\sigma}
$$

the finally piece of your puzzle is the condition that $x(t=0)=1$ to get the result that you show. If thats the case then
$$
x(t) = \dfrac{W\left[\sigma \mathrm{e}^{\left(\sigma -(\sigma+1)t\right)}\right]}{\sigma}
$$

Comment: so many uses of the word "thus" :/!